# Comparing data frames to extract specific values

Tags: r, date, merge, posixct

I have two dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
             Date = c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00"))

df2 <- data.frame(Group = c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","E","E","F","F"),
              Date = c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-12 10:42:00","2018-04-13 10:03:00","2018-04-13 11:21:00","2018-04-14 08:17:00","2018-04-14 10:32:00","2018-04-14 22:44:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-15 11:17:00","2018-04-16 16:56:00","2018-04-16 20:01:00","2018-04-17 11:15:00","2018-04-17 11:20:00"))
```

I would like to do two things. First, by group, I would like to compare the Date column in df to those in df2 and extract the datesDate that are either an exact match or, if there is no exact match, pull the Date from df2 that is both closest and prior to the Date in df.

Second, by group, I would like to compare the Date column in df to those in df2 and extract the Date if there is an exact match or, if there is no exact match, pull the Date from df2 that is nearest, regardless of if its before the Date in df.

So the result should like like the following for this example:

```
result <- data.frame(Group = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                 Date = c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:03:00","2018-04-14 14:30:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 07:28:00","2018-04-17 11:17:00"),
                 Return1 = c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 10:03:00","2018-04-14 10:32:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00",NA,"2018-04-17 11:15:00"),
                 Return2 = c("2018-04-12 08:56:00","2018-04-13 11:21:00","2018-04-14 10:32:00","2018-04-15 03:10:00","2018-04-16 16:56:00","2018-04-17 11:15:00"))
```

Comment: The code to recreate result does not work (Group has more elements thant the other columns). Also, what have you tried to solve your problem ?

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the heads up. I just updated the result

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think you are looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

df <- df %>% mutate(Date = parse_date_time(Date, orders = "ymd HMS"))
df2 <- df2 %>% mutate(Date = parse_date_time(Date, orders = "ymd HMS")) %>% mutate(Result1 = Date)
df3 <- df2 %>% rename(Result2 = Result1)

setDT(df)
setDT(df2)
setDT(df3)

setkey(df,Group, Date)
setkey(df2,Group, Date)
setkey(df3,Group, Date)

list(df2[df, roll = Inf], df3[df, roll = "nearest"]) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = c("Group", "Date"))

#   Group                Date             Result1             Result2
# 1     A 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00
# 2     B 2018-04-13 11:03:00 2018-04-13 10:03:00 2018-04-13 11:21:00
# 3     C 2018-04-14 14:30:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00
# 4     D 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00
# 5     E 2018-04-16 07:28:00                <NA> 2018-04-16 16:56:00
# 6     F 2018-04-17 11:17:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution using only base R :

```
# convert the dates from string to POSIXct
d1 <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)
d2 <- as.POSIXct(df2$Date)
# create a matrix m[df rows, df2 rows] with the difference between 
# the dates (df$Date - df2Date); where df row group != df2 row group set NA
m <- outer(1:nrow(df),1:nrow(df2),
           function(i,j){ ifelse(df$Group[i]!=df2$Group[j],NA,d1[i]-d2[j]) } )

# copy df into res
res <- df
# compute Return1 using matrix m 
# (for each row choose the first having minimum difference>= 0)
res$Return1 <- apply(m,1,function(r){o=order(r);df2$Date[o[r[o]>=0][1]]})
# compute Return2 using matrix m 
# (for each row choose the first having the min absolute difference)
res$Return2 <- apply(m,1,function(r)df2$Date[order(abs(r))[1]])

> res
  Group                Date             Return1             Return2
1     A 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00
2     B 2018-04-13 11:03:00 2018-04-13 10:03:00 2018-04-13 11:21:00
3     C 2018-04-14 14:30:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00
4     D 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00
5     E 2018-04-16 07:28:00                <NA> 2018-04-16 16:56:00
6     F 2018-04-17 11:17:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00
```

And this is another possible solution (always using base R) probably more efficient :

```
# convert the dates from string to POSIXct
d1 <- as.POSIXct(df$Date)
d2 <- as.POSIXct(df2$Date)
# split the row-indexes of df2 into a list of indexes by Group
df2splits <- split(1:nrow(df2),df2$Group)
# for each row of df, save the index of df2split list corresponding to the same Group
splitIdxs <- match(df$Group,names(df2splits))
# compute Return1 using sapply and the previously created structures
res$Return1 <- sapply(1:nrow(df),
               function(i){
                 idx <- df2splits[[splitIdxs[i]]]
                 differ <- d1[i] - d2[idx]
                 o=order(differ)
                 df2$Date[idx][o[differ[o]>=0][1]]
               })
# compute Return2 using sapply and the previously created structures
res$Return2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df),
               function(i){
                 idx <- df2splits[[splitIdxs[i]]]
                 differ <- d1[i] - d2[idx]
                 df2$Date[idx][order(abs(differ))[1]]
               })

> res
  Group                Date             Return1             Return2
1     A 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00 2018-04-12 08:56:00
2     B 2018-04-13 11:03:00 2018-04-13 10:03:00 2018-04-13 11:21:00
3     C 2018-04-14 14:30:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00 2018-04-14 10:32:00
4     D 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00 2018-04-15 03:10:00
5     E 2018-04-16 07:28:00                <NA> 2018-04-16 16:56:00
6     F 2018-04-17 11:17:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00 2018-04-17 11:15:00
```